# Python shell not printing list, only printing <type 'list'>

Tags: python, list, shell, output

I have a really simple program in Python, but it's not printing out the list in the shell.

The program is:

```
list1 = [20]
print "list1 = ", list

def change(alist):
    alist.append(100)

change(list1)   
print "list1 = ", list
```

When I try it in shell, I get

```
>>> import test
list1 =  <type 'list'>
list1 =  <type 'list'>
```

How do I print out the actual values in the list?

Comment: You've made a typo, friend. Try printing list1 instead of list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are printing the `list` type.  To print `list1`, do:

```
print "list1 = ", list1
```